# Twig and controller in Symfony

Tags: php, html, symfony, symfony-2.1

I have a form made in Twig and I want to pass the values of this form to my database, so how do I pass the Twig values to the controller?

In the first photo is the form that I created in twig
 [Formulario twing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dQay.png)

In the second picture is the controller (the entities, and the connection with the database with doctrine orm is complete too), it is only necessary to know how to take the form data and to pass to the controller
  [Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRe0d.png)

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. It looks like you're misunderstanding how things works in Symfony, and it's hard to guess what you're trying to do. Code samples would be helpful too.

Comment: I'm new to symfony, so it's kind of complicated for me, I updated the question with photos, see if now you understand

Answer (score 0):

In [official](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/registration_form.html) documentation you can find flow, how create entity, form, twig template and set data in database.

If you need get data from form use this:

```
   if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // -------- Hear you take data --------
            $ideda = $form->get('ideda')->getData();
            $email = $form->get('email')->getData();
            $telemovel = $form->get('telemovel')->getData();
            // ---------- Hear you set data's ---------
            $usuario -> setIdeda($ideda);
            $usuario -> setEmail ($email );
            $usuario -> setTelemovel($telemovel);
        }):
```

Comment: I have created entities, database, and everything is working perfectly, now the form I created from pure html, I updated the question with some photos

Answer (score 0):

When form submits you will get a POST request to the same URL that it was built in.
Stick to this tutorial:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html

Comment: The problem is that I created the form with html codes, I updated the question with some photos, take a look

Answer (score 0):

If you create a form with html and not symfony form you must manually handle form and other step.
you must submit your form to you controller route that seems is `cadastrarAction()`.

Don't forget to declare route with **POST** method for `cadastrarAction()`.

In controller you can access posted data from request argument like this.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class FooController extends Controller { 

    cadastrarAction(Request $request)
    {
        // Find what you exactly want. if you want to get query use this
        $request->getQueryString()
    }
}
```

This is bad practice that declare form manually. you must use `FormType` for easily handle and persist form to database. use [symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html) official site for more information about form and entity.